# Shrink <select> element to fit in nested flexbox

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, flexbox

I am trying to make some `<select>` elements shrink to fit horizontally inside a vertical flexbox, with a wrapper around each of them. In the case of the example below, I would like the red box to never extend beyond the select element (dropdown), but the select element should shrink to fit.

The two possibilities I have tried are below: in case 1 the container behaves properly at small scales (the select box shrinks), and in case 2 the red box behaves properly at wide scales (the red box does not grow too wide). Is there a way to combine these behaviours?

```css
div, label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 90px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-color: red;
}

.align-stretch { align-self: stretch }

.align-start { align-self: flex-start }

select {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Resize this box</p>
  <label class="align-stretch">
    C1:
    <select>
      <option>This one is stretchy</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="align-start">
    C2:
    <select>
      <option>This is start-aligned</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Case 1 works fine for me both expanding and retracting in Chrome. What browsers are you using?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I’m using Firefox

Comment: @ObsidianAge this is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/KMHTgrV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated solution** (fixes the issue of the parent element’s padding):

Use `max-width: max-content;` and keep the stretch behavior

```css
div,
label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 90px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.align-stretch {
  align-self: stretch;
  max-width: max-content;
}

select {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Resize this box</p>
  <label class="align-stretch">
    C2:
    <select>
      <option>This one is stretchy</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

---

**Original solution**: add `max-width: 100%` to the `flex-start` case. Note that this does not respect the parent element’s padding.

```css
div, label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 90px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-color: red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.align-stretch { align-self: stretch }

.align-start { align-self: flex-start; max-width:100%; }

select {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Resize this box</p>
  <label class="align-stretch">
    C1:
    <select>
      <option>This one is stretchy</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="align-start">
    C2:
    <select>
      <option>This is start-aligned</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn’t take account of the padding on the parent, so the red box gets too close to the parent. Is it possible to account for this without knowing the padding value in pixels and subtracting it?

Comment: @CharlieHarding updated the code, you need to add `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: @CharlieHarding added another idea

Comment: Thanks Temani, it was the `max-width: max-content` that solved it for me, and so made me accept it 

Comment: Out of interest, do you know how I would right-align the red box when it’s wide enough? `margin-left: auto` cancels out the `align-self: stretch`

Comment: @CharlieHarding you can use direction: https://jsfiddle.net/ye4q0ptb/

Comment: That seems slightly dangerous if I put text directly in the container, but OK